# Can I initialize the same image twice in different functions in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have an ImageButton that I initialized in my OnCreate() function, and I also want to use it in a separate function, when my spinner is activated, but I can't access the imagebutton that has been initalized.

Can I just initalize the image button again in the OnSpinnerSelection() function or is that bad practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do would be to initialize the ImageButton outside the onCreate method.
Then, it becomes a global variable and can be used in any method.

Like this :

```
ImageButton im;

@Override

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// set content view

im = (ImageButton)findViewbyId(R.id.<id>);

// other code 

}
```

Comment: Ohh ok, so what I did instead was do ImageButton im = findViewbyID(R.id.<id>) in each function, but instead I only initialize it once globally, then assign it as many times as I want inside the functions?

Comment: Yes. Do that for your solution.

Comment: Follow the code given above. Declare globally but initialize in onCreate ()

Comment: Ahh ok I understand, sorry I confused declare with initialize for a second lolm thanks!